# what is replaced elements in css?

Tags: html, css, element

I can't understand definitely what is replaced elements

I expect to be the elements whose need an attribute to show output on the browser,,i know that there is many replaced elements such as  img and video and iframe ,but I cant understand how to identify any replaced element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

Comment: There is a more discursive discussion of replaced elements at https://www.sitepoint.com/replaced-elements-html-myths-realities/#:~:text=object%20%E2%80%93%20Treated%20as%20a%20replaced%20element%20when,with%20the%20same%20intrinsic%20dimensions%20as%20the%20element. which seems to be fairly accurate and goes into some detail on each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Replaced elements

"In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS; they're external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS formatting model."

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

(Cited from [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element))